# Showing Java Gui application on browser

Tags: java, swing, jsp, applet, java-web-start

I have made a `Java` GUI standalone application for my desktop. It is also connected to `MySQl` database to save data of users in a registration process like name,mail-id,passwords etc.

**Problem**

But now I want to show this same GUI interface in a browser but on searching this query I got information about Applet and JSP. The articles included about real web applications which included some protocols and server of which I am not aware. I just want to run it on my browser and use it like a signup/login form.

**Question**

Creating the entire GUI in Applet will be pretty hectic. Is there any way to directly embed/show my app in the browser or any method so that I can just copy the entire code of my app in some jsp/applet file and run it?

Thank You.

Comment: Look at "java web start", do not use applets, they are soon lo longer supported. With java web start you can run your java program out of a browser (but will open a java application on your desktop in the end). If this is not what you want, maybe the JSP direction is better, but probably will require some refactoring

Comment: I will surely look into Java Web Start to solve my issue.Thank You.